# Personalizar una etiqueta option en select2

Tags: html, css, select2

Quisiera saber como puedo modificar el estilo de una opcion especifica en un select.

Mi select trae unos registros de la BD y de forma manual le agrego una opcion que sea añadir nuevo campo, y este abre una modal, pero quisiera que esa opcion se vea en negrilla, las demas que tengan el diseño por defecto.

Este es mi select

```
<select id="autore_id" name="autore_id" class="form-select block w-full mt-1 rounded border-gray-300 select2"></select>
```

Aqui lo vinculo con select2

```
$(".select2").select2({theme: "bootstrap-5"});
```

Aqui esta llenando el select mediante ajax.

```
$.ajax({
...
$('#autore_id').append(`<option value="${element.autores[i].id}">${element.autores[i].nombre</option>`);
```

Aqui le ingreso un campo de insertar nuevo registro.

```
$('#autore_id').append(`<option value="1000" class="font-weight-bold">Agregar autor</option>`);
```

Se que se puede colocar negrilla pero no encuentro como a una sola opción

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar simplemente la etiqueta `<b>` dentro del `option`, de la siguiente forma

```
$('#autore_id').append(`<option value="1000">
 <b>Agregar autor</b>
</option>`);
```

Comment: He probado esta forma con anterioridad y no me funciona, me imprime el texto pero la negrita no.

Comment: tambien puede que esto te sirva:

$('#autore_id').append(`<option value="1000" style="font-weight: 700;">
 Agregar autor
</option>`);

Answer (score 0):

Si entendi lo que quieres hacer ¿seria algo como esto?

```js
var autores = [];
function getAuthors(){
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    autores.push({id: i+1, text: "Nombre " + (i+1)});
  }
}

$("#loadData").click(function(){
    getAuthors();
  
    for(var i=0; i<autores.length; i++){
    console.log(autores[i]);
        $('#autore_id').append('<option value=' + autores[i].id + '>' + autores[i].text + '</option>');
  }
  
  $("#autore_id").select2().trigger('change');

    $('#autore_id').append('<option class="negrita" value=1000>Agregar autor</option>');
})
```

```css
.form-select{
  width: 300px;
}

.negrita {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.css">
<button id="loadData">
Cargar datos
</button>
<select id="autore_id" name="autore_id" class="form-select block w-full mt-1 rounded border-gray-300 select2">

</select>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me funciona, me podrias indicar que funcion tiene trigger en este caso me esta borrando todos los elementos del select. Gracias

Comment: Este ejemplo es solo javascript puro, tal vez estan limpiando el select2 en alguno momento o te falta llamar .trigger('change'); despues de agregarle nuevos datos

Comment: Puedes validar si en algun punto estas sobrescribiendo el select2 a eso suena o refrescando algo, porque por poner un append no deberia "borrarte todos los elementos", en alguna parte del codigo estas volviendo a limpiar el combo.

Comment: Lo que está ocasionado el error es el triggers, aún no puedo solucionarlo pero se que proviene de ahí, porque cuando coloca la opción de agregar autor sin negrilla lo toma bien pero cuando trato de hacer el trigger y aplicar la negrilla el select pierde el formato.

Comment: Vuelvele a dar formato despues del trigger:  .select2();  <-- asi nadamas

Comment: Sucede lo mismo, lo que me parece curioso es que si puedo añadir el Item pero la negrilla no, ya he probado, con clase de boostrap, con selectores y dentro de la misma etiqueta y solo se imprime el texto sin el formato.

Comment: Pero el error de que no salgan items sucede es por el trigger, si no lo uso, me salen los items de la bd y el custom, mientras que con trigger ninguna opcion me aparece.

Comment: Ok, bien entonces si no sale la negrita algun css eta sobrescribiendo tu estilo, tienes que validarlo en el dev tools del brosewer y jugar con los estilos alli para ver cual es el detalle, algo que puedes hacer, pero que no recomiendo es agregar un inline style

Comment: Ya vi que el inline style no funciona, bueno otra cosa es poner !Imporant en el css... lo que dices suena  a que otra cosa esta sobre escribiendo tu estilo

Comment: Si siempre es el ultimo elmento del select2, puedes poner este css:  `.select2-results> li:last-child {  
  font-weight: bold;
 }`